# How to add a Date Format to convert Excel Date into a Normal Date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am looking for some help in regards to changing the format of some dates that I have in a table after I run an Update Script to convert Excel Dates into Normal Dates.

The following is my create and insert statements:

```
    CREATE TABLE `date_checks` 
    (  
    `Start_Date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
    );
```

My Insert Statements:

```
INSERT INTO `date_checks` (`Start_Date`) VALUES
('43194'),
('43221'),
('43251'),
('43248');
```

I then ran the following statement which converted the Excel Dates to normal Dates:

```
UPDATE abu_business_util_1119.date_checks SET Start_Date = DATE('1899-12-30') + INTERVAL Start_Date DAY WHERE Start_Date REGEXP '^[0-9]{5}$';
```

This gives me the following output:

```
Start_Date
2018-04-04
2018-05-01
2018-05-31
2018-05-28
```

What I would like is for the date to be converted as DD-MM-YYYY rather than YYYY-MM-DD but I am not sure what part of my update script I need to change to add a new format. I would like my final result to look like:

Desirable Output

```
Start_Date
04-04-2018
01-05-2018
31-05-2018
28-05-2018
```

If somebody could please advise on how I can fix this.

Thanks

Comment: You date is saved in mysql format, when you retrieve it you can use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format to get your desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have updated to put dates into a date format;

`ALTER TABLE date_checks MODIFY Start_Date DATE`

to move this to a date stored column.

As @nbk said, use [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) when retrieving the value, or let your application code perform the formatting as it will be a date type object when retrieved.

Comment: Thanks nbk and danblack for your clear explanations very much appreciated.